# Fetching selected radio button in wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

In WinForms I've used panel to group radio buttons and then this code to fetch selected radio button

```
var checkedValue = panelMyPanel.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>()
                        .FirstOrDefault(r => r.Checked);
```

Now I want to translate this to wpf and inside xaml I added radio buttons

```
 <RadioButton GroupName="myGroup" Name="Option1" Content="option one" IsChecked="True"  Width="40"/>
 <RadioButton GroupName="myGroup" Name="Option2" Content="option two" IsChecked="False" Width="80"/>
 <RadioButton GroupName="myGroup" Name="Option3" Content="option three" IsChecked="False" Width="60"/>
```

how to know which radio btn is selected in code behind?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Almost same, suppose these are child of stackPanels, it will be like this:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="panel">
  <RadioButton/>
  <RadioButton/>
  <RadioButton/>
</StackPanel>
```

Code:

```
var checkedValue = panel.Children.OfType<RadioButton>()
                 .FirstOrDefault(r => r.IsChecked.HasValue && r.IsChecked.Value);
```

Since radio button `IsChecked` property is **nullable bool**, so you need to check first `HasValue` and then `Value`.